# How to print list of all threads in C++ application?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, logging

How can I print list of threads (preferably names) running in my C++ application in POSIX OS (say Linux)?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a directory listing of `/proc/self/task` to get a list of thread ids. Note that this is Linux specific; not portable to all POSIX.

You can get the name of each thread using `pthread_getname_np`. The name of a thread defaults to the name of the program. This is glibc specific function; not portable to all POSIX or even all Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Other options to do the same thing:

1) If you have the application name

Use `ps -C <application name> -T`

- `-C` denotes command name should follow after it
- `-T` lists all the threads with SPIDs

2) If you have process id,

Use `ps -p <process id> -T`

- `-p` denotes process id should follow after it
- `-T` lists all the threads with SPIDs

Comment: Instead of `-e` and grep, use `-p $my_pid` to let ps filter the threads owned by the process.